# PG Restore function not working on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, database-backups, pg

I'm trying to restore a backup to my localhost machine to review the data - so that I can actually make sure the backup is working. I'm using Heroku, postgres, and rails.

I clean installed the app, so there is no data in the localhost database. I ran db:reset, and db:migrate.

Here is the string I'm trying to use for pg_restore:

```
 pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -p 3000 -U ian -d backup_production latest.dump
```

The error I receive says:

"connection to database "backup_production" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly"

I've never had to do this before, so any help would be appreciated. I assume that development is what localhost uses (instead of test or production)?

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'll answer any question you may have.

Thanks a lot.

edit,. Here is a question, for this database string I assumed that I need to to use all the localhost information, because I created a backup using heroku capture/download. Am I wrong in that assumption? Should I instead be using the database name and port, etc, from the heroku credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I shouldn't have added the port. Removing -p 3000 , made this command work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Edit the postgre configuration file typing in terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/POSTGRE_VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Then change your configuration to this

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             all                                     trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Restart your postgre server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

This should be the solution to access without password